# Writing Applications with C

Tags: c, driver, firmware

I took a lot of time to learn about C, and pointers and arrays and strings. But now I want to know how to apply all this. The title says Applications, but I also want to know how to write firmware, and device drivers and kernels. If you could point me to books,on line resources, and things of this nature.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Comment: This question is too broad. Please avoid asking questions for recommendations on books.

Comment: If you're looking for books, try Amazon. For online resources, try Google.

Comment: The similar question has been already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222763/how-should-i-get-started-on-writing-device-drivers

Comment: The best way to learn is *not* to have a goal, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to learn write C program is to actually find a project to work on. However, you need to get enough knowledge in order to achieve this. According to my understanding, most of the C language beginners learned C and just have some numbers printed in the `console`(black box). C is a low-level language, sometimes very annoying. I think the way a programming language need to cultivate interest, black box is clearly not a good way. So, I suggest that in the process of learning C language, also combine with API. Teaching people to write a program with the interface is better than people all day long face the black box. Here are some books I recommend:

```
 1. The C programming Language
 2. C Primer Plus
```